# How do you create the rising cinematic sfx seen in most trailers?

Tags: trailer, sfx, sound-design, sound-effects, suggestion

Looking for some help on how to create all types of rising sfx whether it be for action movies or horror movies.

Comment: @NAS, what do you mean by rising? Pitch, intensity, volume?

Comment: is this what you mean the sound at 1:28 from the signal trailer and the sound 1:20 from prometheus trailer ..........
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwgfeR2pMuE#t=92 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQgnnsqysZE#t=80

Answer (score 1):

Start with taking various hits and impacts, process them with a long tailed reverberation, render, make a copy of processed sound and reverse it. 
To enrich your newborn effects, add some other elements like vocals, strings, stretched animal roars or synthetic whooshes - whatever you may need. :)

Comment: Hey that's great but I'm looking for a specific sound it has that rising tension of a bunch of stretched out strings seen in a ton of movie trailers. Do you know the exact one i'm talking about?

Comment: You can look for specific patches in the Mophestra library or sound libraries from Sanple Logic (The Elements or Ambient Impact Rhythms). You'll need NI Kontakt though.